# Spark dataset and scala.ScalaReflectionException: type V is not a class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following classes:

```
case class S1(value: String, ws: Map[Int, String])
case class S2(value: String, ws: Map[Int, String], dep: BS)
```

As shown above, these two have one different field which is `BS`

The code below works fine.

```
sparkSQL.createDataset(Seq(S1("heloo", Map(0 -> "0")))).foreach(x => println(x))
```

The code below works also fine and it is the `BS` class by itself.

```
sparkSQL.createDataset(Seq(BS(List(0), List(Edge(0, 1, DepRelation("0-->1", "", "")))))).foreach(x => println(x))
```

Now if I use `S2` which is basically `S1` and a `BS` class, I get a runtime error message:

```
sparkSQL.createDataset(Seq(S2("heloo", Map(0 -> "0"), BS(List(0), List(Edge(0, 1, DepRelation("0-->1", "", ""))))))).foreach(x => println(x))

Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException: type V is not a class
    at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asClass(Symbols.scala:275)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asClass(Symbols.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.getClassFromType(ScalaReflection.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$dataTypeFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$dataTypeFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:66)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:809)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$dataTypeFor(ScalaReflection.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.toCatalystArray$1(ScalaReflection.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:455)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:809)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:455)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:809)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:455)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:809)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.LowPrioritySQLImplicits$class.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:33)
```

And here is my env:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("test")
    .setMaster("local[*]")

val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
val sparkSQL = new SQLContext(spark)

import sparkSQL.implicits._
```

--Edited 1-- Edge and DepRel definitions per request in comments

```
case class Edge[V,E](from:V, to:V, label:E)
case class DepRelation(vl:String)
```

Comment: could you also share what `Edge` and `DepRelation` classes are?

Comment: @LokeshYadav please look at the edits

Comment: Thanks, could you also provide the definition for `BS` class? I created a definition of `BS`by seeing the usage but was unable to reproduce the issue with that. Also, a minor thing point out: `DepRelation` in the definition you provided takes in just 1 input while in the code its taking 3 inputs. Which one to consider?

Comment: @LokeshYadav Thanks, I cannot provide BS because I have to provide so many other things which are not feasible give the scope of StackOverflow, I had simplified DepRelation, it has 3 String fields.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious from your error stack trace that it's failing for the following.

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException: type V is not a class
```

So, here the main pain point is Type V which you have used to define the following case class.

```
case class Edge[V,E](from:V, to:V, label:E)
```

What types are V (and E as well?). For example Are they String/Int/Double? Could you please show me the code here? (Because here lies the answer of your question)

If you are already sure about the type information of those V and E, then try to rewrite your case class definition of Edge like the following (by inferring to actual type). For e.g.

```
case class Edge[V: Int,E: Int](from:V, to:V, label:E)
```

It might solve your problem or you may need to look down further on your type V.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but As you can see in my examples, it works if I use it alone and it just fails when using it in another case class, that case class also work but itself. For some reason, it does not compose!